# dredge subset with GAM

Tags: subset

I am trying to build a group of GAM models using my dataset but have some specific rules that the models must follow.  Therefore, I am trying to use pdredge with a subset to limit the models generated for results.  Here is the code I have:

```
# Dredge for GAMs
# using Ground_10 as dependent variable, R_Data_v9
# using only observations with no inundation (i.e., xarea=0)

# To run on Rachel's laptop:
# source("C:/Users/Davidson/Documents/Dana Anderson/Japan ignition/R scripts/gam_dredge_1.R")
# or to run on cluster
# source("gam_dredge_1.R")

# LOAD LIBRARIES

library(mgcv)
library(MuMIn)
library(MASS)
library(parallel)

# READ IN DATA

# To read it from Dana's computer:
data<-read.table("C:/.../R_Data_v9_ground_10.txt", header=TRUE)
#note: deleted actual location of data for security reasons.



# Select only those observations with no inundation
data_gm<-subset(data,xarea==0)
print("data loaded")
# Assign variable names
ground_10<-data_gm$ground_10
xpsa03<-data_gm$xpsa03
xpgv<-data_gm$xpgv
xpga<-data_gm$xpga
xii<-data_gm$xii
xpsa10<-data_gm$xpsa10
xpsa30<-data_gm$xpsa30
xres<-data_gm$xres
xcom<-data_gm$xcom
xindus<-data_gm$xindus
xratio<-data_gm$xratio
xdam1<-data_gm$xdam1
xdam2<-data_gm$xdam2
xdam3<-data_gm$xdam3
xpdam1<-data_gm$xpdam1
xpdam2<-data_gm$xpdam2
xpdam3<-data_gm$xpdam3
xdam123<-data_gm$xdam123
xpdam123<-data_gm$xpdam123
xpop<-data_gm$xpop
xestab<-data_gm$xestab
xwood<-data_gm$xwood

# SET UP CLUSTER

# Detect number of cores on computer
detectCores()

# Determine cluster type (mine is a PSOCK)
clusterType <- if(length(find.package("snow", quiet = TRUE))) "SOCK" else "PSOCK"

# Set up a cluster with number of cores specified as result of detectCores() 
#   and call it "clust" 
# For laptop with 4 cores
clust <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 4), type = clusterType)


# Load required packages onto worker nodes
#   (in this example, load packages {MASS} and {MuMIn} to be used by pdredg)
clusterEvalQ(clust,library(mgcv))
clusterEvalQ(clust,library(MuMIn))

#GAM RUNS:

gam1<-gam(ground_10~s(xii,k=2)+s(xpga,k=2)+s(xpgv,k=2)+s(xpsa03,k=2)+s(xpsa10,k=2)+s(xpsa30,k=2)+
s(xpop,k=2)+s(xres,k=2)+s(xestab,k=2)+s(xcom,k=2)+
s(xindus,k=2)+
s(xpdam1,k=2)+s(xpdam2,k=2)+s(xpdam3,k=2)+s(xpdam123,k=2)+
s(xwood,k=2)+
s(xdam1,k=2)+s(xdam2,k=2)+s(xdam123,k=2))


# Export data and any objects the modeling function will use 
#    into the cluster worker nodes
clusterExport(clust,c("data_gm","gam1","ground_10", "xii", "xpga", "xpgv", "xpsa03", "xpsa10", "xpsa30", "xpop", "xres", "xestab", "xcom", "xindus","xpdam1", "xpdam2", "xpdam3", "xpdam123", "xwood", "xdam1", "xdam2", "xdam3", "xdam123"))

# Run pdredge using subsetting so as to allow no more than 1 ground motion covariate at a time

pdd.gam1<-pdredge(gam1, cluster=clust,      
        subset=(!('s(xii, k=2)'&'s(xpga, k=2)') & !'(s(xii, k=2)' &'s(xpgv, k=2)') & !('s(xii,k=2)'&'s(xpsa03,k=2)') & !('s(xii, k=2)'&'s(xpsa10,k=2)') & !('s(xii, k=2)'&'s(xpsa30,k=2)') & !('s(xpga, k=2)'&'s(xpgv, k=2)')       
              & !('s(xpga, k=2)'&'s(xpsa03,k=2)') & !('s(xpga,k=2)' &'s(xpsa10,k=2)') & !('s(xpga,k=2)'&'s(xpsa30,k=2)') & !('s(xpgv,k=2)'&'s(xpsa03,k=2)') & !('s(xpgv,k=2)'&'s(xpsa10,k=2)') & !('s(xpgv,k=2)'&'s(xpsa30,k=2)')       
              & !('s(xpsa03,k=2)'&'s(xpsa10,k=2)') & !('s(xpsa03,k=2)'&'s(xpsa30,k=2)') & !('s(xpsa10,k=2)'&'s(xpsa30,k=2)')        
              & !('s(xpop,k=2)'&'s(xres,k=2)') & !('s(xpop,k=2)'&'s(xestab,k=2)') & !('s(xpop,k=2)'&'s(xcom,k=2)') & !('s(xres,k=2)'&'s(xestab,k=2)') & !('s(xres,k=2)'&'s(xcom,k=2)') & !('s(xestab,k=2)'&'s(xcom,k=2)')       
              & !('s(xpdam1,k=2)'&'s(xpdam123,k=2)' & !('s(xpdam2,k=2)'&'s(xpdam123,k=2)') & !('s(xpdam3,k=2)'&'s(xpdam123,k=2)')       
            & !('s(xdam1,k=2)'&'s(xdam2,k=2)') & !('s(xdam1,k=2)'&'s(xdam3,k=2)') & !('s(xdam1,k=2)'&'s(xdam123,k=2)') & !('s(xdam2,k=2)'&'s(xdam3,k=2)') & !('s(xdam2,k=2)'& 's(xdam123,k=2)') & !('s(xdam3,k=2)'&'s(xdam123,k=2)')),rank=function(x) summary(x)$sp.criterion, extra=c(GCV=function(x) summary(x)$sp.criterion, "AIC"))
```

However, everytime I run this, it comes up with the following error:

> Error in pdredge(gam1, cluster = clust, subset = (!(`s(xii,k=2)` & `s(xpga,k=2)`) &  : 
>     unrecognized names in 'subset' expression: "s(xii,k=2)", "s(xpga,k=2)", "s(xpgv,k=2)", "s(xpsa03,k=2)", "s(xpsa10,k=2)", "s(xpsa30,k=2)", "s(xpop,k=2)", "s(xres,k=2)", "s(xestab,k=2)", "s(xcom,k=2)", "s(xpdam1,k=2)", "s(xpdam123,k=2)", "s(xpdam2,k=2)", "s(xpdam3,k=2)", "s(xdam1,k=2)", "s(xdam2,k=2)", "s(xdam3,k=2)" and "s(xdam123,k=2)"

Please help me try to figure this out! I have tried everything I could possibly think of!
Thanks, Dana

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar problem. I assume you are following the help for subsetting in dredge(): i.e. "Compound model terms (such as ‘as-is’ expressions within I() or smooths in gam) should be treated as non-syntactic names and enclosed in back-ticks, e.g.

```
subset = ‘s(x, k = 2)‘ || ‘I(log(x))‘
```

I found that I could only get this to work using ` (back-ticks!) rather than the character shown in the help example, i.e. a ‘ (which seems to me to be a single quote).

Also, dredge() seems to require you to exactly match the spacing that it uses internally

i.e.
In my case, my model was

```
M1<-gam(PLNK ~ s(CX, k=5) + s(CHL, k=5) + s(HC, k=5) + s(sqHUM, k=5) 
+ s(sqHDIST, k=5) + s(SSTL, k=5) + s(WV, k=5) + AT, data=z, 
family=Gamma (link=log))
```

I wanted to exclude models with both WV and SSTL

```
subset=!(`s(CHL, k = 5)` & `s(WV, k=5)`)
```

did not work, BUT

```
subset=!(`s(CHL, k = 5)` & `s(WV, k = 5)`)
```

did.

I gleaned the internal formatting used by dredge by running dredge without the subset parameter and then looking at the models in the resulting data frame.

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'getAllTerms' function on the global model to list all terms in the correct form.